# Rn the jQuery code dynamically (if my body add the div class)

Tags: javascript, jquery

My body selector has added new class `st--sticky-header` dynamically. (after scroll)

I make a jQuery code and this is work in console browser, but this code work only static. I would like, that my code run dynamically, if my body class `st--sticky-header` will be added dynamically.

```
    $('.filter--facet-container').each(function () {
        if ($(this).children().length <= 5) {
            $(".action--filter-btn").css("display", "none");
            $(".action--sort.action--content.block").css("margin-bottom", "10px");
        }

        if ($(this).children().length <= 4) {
            $(".filter--container-additional").css({
                paddingBottom: "20px",
                height: "125px"
            });

// this code - start

            if ($("body").hasClass("st--sticky-header")) {
                $(".filter--container-additional").css({
                    height: "100px"
                });
            }

            else {
                $(".filter--container-additional").css({
                    height: "125px"
                });
            }

// this code - end
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why not just run the code when you add the class to `body`? Or, since you're only changing CSS, add it into your stylesheet.

Comment: @BenM - `if ($("body").hasClass("st--sticky-header")) {...`

Comment: Since you're only modifying CSS values, use CSS... `body.st--sticky-header { height: 100px }`

Comment: @Archer, I can't do this, because the `height: 100px` can be only if `($(this).children().length <= 4)`

Comment: `I would like, that my code run dynamically, if my body class st--sticky-header will be added dynamically.` Execute the code when you add the class.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve all of this without using jQuery, since you're only modifying CSS. By adding `body` to the selector, we make it more specific, so it will override the previous definitions for `.filter--container-additional`.

Just add the following to your CSS:

```
.filter--container-additional {
  height: 125px;
}

body.st--sticky-header .filter--container-additional {
  height: 100px;
}
```

Further to your comment, you can add another class if `.filter--facet-container` has `<=` 4 children using jQuery:

```
if( $('.filter--facet-container').children() <= 4 )
{
  $('body').addClass('four-or-less');
}
```

And then further update your CSS as follows:

```
body.four-or-less .filter--container-additional {
  height: 125px;
}

body.four-or-less.st--sticky-header .filter--container-additional {
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: The question isn't particularly clear.  They want this to happen when the number of child elements changes, not just when they load the page.

Comment: Hmm, how have you inferred that?

Comment: `My body selector has added new class st--sticky-header dynamically. (after scroll)` and `I would like, that my code run dynamically`.  It already does exactly what they need, but doesn't change anything if `.children().length` changes.  Yes, it's vague, but my gut tells me that's what they mean.  I've asked them a pertinent question anyway.